# jQuery's .height() function returns 0, when device width is less than 1000px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, viewport

I have following code snippet for finding the height of a div.

This returns 1400px, when viewed in device with more, than 1000px width. This is what I wanted to work in all viewports, but when viewed in a device with less than 1000px width, it returns 0.

```
var $slideheight=parseInt($('.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active').height());
```

The **div** has `.swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active` classes and `display:block` style property and also contains the HTML contents.

I could not figure out why my code returns 0 in a viewport less, than 1000px width, while it works for a viewport more, than 1000px width.

Comment: are you using above statement in `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: can you set up code example that replicates the problem, with all the html  layout and css styles?
also in question header you say about device height, and in description about device width

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal yes I wrote it `$(document).ready(function(){});` also tried `$(window).load(function(){});`

Comment: @paulitto I have to find the height of the div so that I could make an interaction as per height of the div. But I am not being able to get the height of the div when the device width is changed to less than 1000px.

Comment: @AryanTwanju ok, here's a quick [example](https://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/3me4x53m/1/) for you that satisfies what you have described,  and still shows 1400 height with different viewport widths and in mobile emulation mode in chrome.
Set up similar one that shows the problem. There does not seem to be enough information.

Comment: FYI, when you use `parseInt`, you need to supply the second radix argument as well, e.g. `parseInt(aString, 10)`.

Comment: give us full example

Comment: I've similar problem when I generate dynamically element in my div or when my div is hide when I ask the height. Are you in one of these situations. Please give us more code

Comment: I haven't changed a bit of your code in the fiddle, just that I have set the height to `400px`, and it seems to be working just fine. Here is the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/3me4x53m/8/).

Comment: I have even checked this in the responsive window with a height of `340px`, still it seems to be working just fine. Can you share a bit more of your code?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid `display:block` when it is absolutely positioned because according to jQuery Documentation it is strongly discouraged to call those methods on `<style>` or `<script>` tags. In addition to being a bad practice, the results may also prove unreliable.